# phonegap - Black screen showing after splash screen on blackberry

Tags: html, cordova, blackberry

i've build my app using phonegap online builder, and it works properly on android but on a blackberry device (9800) and after the splash screen it shows a blank black screen with a white horizontal bar (about 5 px ) on the top of screen and nothing else. 
anyone can help me please ?
thanks

Comment: check this link for a solution in sencha .. http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-151188.html?s=38b8a491af587aa62488347320123449

Comment: Any solution without sencha?

Comment: did you got any solution. then please post answer here. I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue and I found that once I ensured this was in the head it worked:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```